# Better way to define this bijection [0,1) to (0,1)

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, proof-writing, cardinals

I have been trying to construct a bijection from $[0,1)$ to $(0,1)$ that my professor was showing me in class.  I think that the function works in terms of being one-to-one and onto. Here's the function 
$$f(x)=\Bigl(\dfrac{2^{n+1}-3}{2^n}\Bigr)-x$$
but in order for this function to work (i.e. be 1-1 and onto), we have to have $$x<\dfrac{2^{n}-1}{2^{n}}$$
This is what the graph looks like.[image: Rough sketch]

My question is whether or not there a better way to construct $f$ so that $x$ doesn't depend on values of $n$.

Comment: Hint.  A continuous bijection can not exist.  You must deal with the point $1$ individually.

Comment: Second hint, it cannot be monotone, so that you need to "blend it" somehow.

Comment: "but I am just unsure of how to write the function so that the constraints on n are there."  What constraints on $n$?  Why do you have $f_n$?  That's a countable number of functions?  Why? You were asked for a bijection?  I kind of don't think you know what you are doing because none of them actually map to (0,1) and they don't seem to be a function. Are you thinking the bijection will be the limit?  But the limit will just be the identity which isn't a biject.  Do you actually *understand* the question?

Comment: What *ARE* you doing?  Each of the functions $f_n(x)$ is of the form $f(x) x + c_n$ where $c_n$ is a constant.  These map $(0, 1] \to (0+c_n, 1 + c_n]$.  None of these map to $(0,1)$ and why do you have a sequence of functions *anyway*.  You were asked for one function.  Do you think you are trying to make a bijection from $N$ to $(0,1]$ (which isn't possible)? and that somehow these $f_n$ are .... something to do with $(0,1]$.

Comment: What you need to do is make *one* function, one function only $g:(0,1) \to (0,1]$ so the the function is one to one (if $x\ne y$ then $f(x) \ne y)$ and onto.  For *every* $y \in (0,1]$ (including $1$) there is a *distinct* $x\in (0,1)$ ($x$ can *not* be $1$) so that $g(x) = g(y)$.  The trick is you need to find an $x; 0< x < 1$ so that $g(x) = 1$.  Then you need to find an $x_1$ so the $g(x_1) = x$, Then an $x_2$ so that $g(x_2) = x_1$ and so on.  All the rest of the numbers in (0,1) can map to themselves.

Answer (score 1):

Let 
$$
 0 \to 0.1 \to 0.01 \to \ldots \to 10^{-n} \to 10^{-n-1} \to \ldots.
$$
So we "hide" $0$ in the infinite sequense within $(0,1)$. Then for each point $$
  x \in (0,1) \setminus \{10^{-n}:n=0,1,2,\ldots\}
$$
we put $x \to x$.